# vagrant dcos install cassandra error

Tags: cassandra, vagrant, dcos

I followed the official vagrant-dcos instruction to install cassandra with minimal setup, by running command below, and got errors. Any idea?

```
dcos package install --options=examples/oinker/pkg-cassandra.json cassandra --yes
```

see error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli/dcoscli/subcommand.py", line 101, in run_and_capture
  File "cli/dcoscli/package/main.py", line 22, in main
  File "cli/dcoscli/util.py", line 22, in wrapper
  File "cli/dcoscli/package/main.py", line 36, in _main
  File "dcos/cmds.py", line 43, in execute
  File "cli/dcoscli/package/main.py", line 322, in _install
  File "dcos/packagemanager.py", line 177, in get_package_version
  File "dcos/packagemanager.py", line 359, in __init__
  File "cli/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 866, in json
  File "json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
  File "json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
  File "json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be issue on cosmos. I restarted whole vagrant and it worked fine.